# Is there any way to filter columns in markdown tables?

Tags: markdown

I have a table written in markdown text. I would like to add filter to a particular column in the table. 
Any way to do this?

Comment: As far as I know it's not possible. Markdown is just a formatting "language" which got no functionality of controlling the values.

Comment: Your mkdown will eventually be turned into an .html file, right? If that's the case, perhaps you may consider working directly on that resulting .html file instead of your .md file. That's the workaround I am considering to solve the same problem. However, watch out for not falling in a maintenance nightmare later.